# How to call a method inside a service from app.module in angular and use the values in Imports

Tags: angular, environment-variables, ngx-logger

I'm moving all the environment related data from angular to external api call so that it can be build once and deployed in multiple environments. For NGX Logger it is imported in `app.module.ts` and the configs for `level` and `serverLogLevel` is fetched from `environment.ts` currently since it varies based on evironments.

This is the current NGXLogger config

```
imports:[
LoggerModule.forRoot({
level: NgxLoggerLevel[env.consolelvl],
serverLogLevel: NgxLogerLevel[env.serverlvl]
})
]
```

I want these env variables to be fetched from api call. How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value for your levels

And later on when you execute your API call you can update the logger config with `partialUpdateConfig`

Attention, this means the logs called before your API call will use the default level

*PS : This requires 5.0.11, if you have an older version you need to use `updateConfig`*